# How to transform data into probabilities

Tags: r, probability-theory

I am trying to create a simple game in which you select a player A, ..., J and each player has stats categories 1, ..., 10 and the values are deterministic.  The data is as follows:

```
players <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
stats <- c("Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3", "Cat4", "Cat5", "Cat6", "Cat7", "Cat8", "Cat9", "Cat10")
values <- matrix(rnorm(100,mean=3,sd=1), 10, 10) #random sample for example
```

The game works by two players facing each other and a stat gets chosen at random and the higher stats wins.  I have tried to use dplyr mutate with the ecdf function to calculate probabilities but I am getting errors with NA coercion.  The aim is to transform each column so that each player has a probability of winning in that stat category.  Then I would like to run a simulation seeing which players have the best chance of winning, so then I can adjust the stats accordingly.

Comment: What is the meaning of matrix `values`?  Related to `players` and `stats`? Better to provide a small example to describe the desired transformation

Comment: Stat A could be "attack" or stat B could be "defence", if player A has attack value 5 and player B has attack value 4 then player A would register a win.  The stats will be pre-determined based on the player "style".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that gives the probability of a contender winning a stat comparison against a than another randomly selected player for a given stat. This works if you have a matrix of stats like the one you provided. The outcomes are win and lose. Ties are broken by a coin toss. Each player competes only once (i.e. regardless of whether they won or lost a comparison with a randomly selected player they do not compete again with another player tournament style).

[Since it was unclear whether the players are columns or rows, I've assumed that players are in rows of the values matrix and stats are in the columns. The code below would only have to be modified slightly if the players were instead in the columns]

```
players <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
stats <- c("Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3", "Cat4", "Cat5", "Cat6", "Cat7", "Cat8", "Cat9", "Cat10")
values <- matrix(rnorm(100,mean=3,sd=1), 10, 10) #random sample for example
dimnames(values) <- list(players, stats)

apply(values, 2, function(x) {
  vapply(x, function(y) {
    wins <- sum(y > x)
    draws <- (sum(y == x) - 1)/2  # Subtract 1 because y can't compete with itself.
    win_prob <- (wins + draws) / (length(x) - 1)
  }, FUN.VALUE = numeric(1))
})
```